# I am getting warnings for semaphores

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pthreads

So I have been all day working on this project, I was checking the errors that I have and as I was fixing them I came to the last part which is the warnings.

the warnings that I am getting are the same: Passing argument 1 of '' from compatible pointer type [enabled by default]
note: expected 'union sem_t*' but argument is of type 'void * (*)(void*)'

please just help me out. I have been stuck on this for several hours now. thanks in advance!

I took off the & from sem_init in both customers and barbers, but it did not work.

```
    #include <unistd.h> //Provides API for POSIX(or UNIX) OS for system calls
    #include <stdio.h> //Standard I/O Routines
    #include <stdlib.h> //For exit() and rand()
    #include <pthread.h> //Threading APIs
    #include <semaphore.h> //Semaphore APIs

    #define MAX 30 //Maximum no. of customers for simulation
    #define MAX_BARBERS 1000

    sem_t customer; //Semaphore
    sem_t barber; //Semaphore
    sem_t mutex; //Semaphore for providing mutially exclusive access

    void *barbers(void *param); //Thread Function
    void *customers(void *param); //Thread Function

    int num_chairs;
    int barbers_total;
    int customers_total;
    int serveMeNext; //Index to choose a candidate for cutting hair

    void wait(); //Randomized delay function

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

      pthread_t barberid[MAX_BARBERS];
      pthread_t customerid[MAX]; //Thread declaration
      int i = 0;

      if(argc != 4){
        printf("Enter 3 arguments (Number of chairs, barbers, customers)\n");
        exit(0);
      }

      num_chairs = atoi(argv[1]);
      barbers_total = atoi(argv[2]);
      customers_total = atoi(argv[3]);
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
      /*Semaphore initialization*/
      sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
      sem_init(customers,0,0);
      sem_init(barbers,0,0);
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
      /*Barber thread initialization*/
      printf("!!Barber Shop Opens!!\n");

      for(i = 0; i <= barbers_total; i++){ //Creation of barbers    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         pthread_create(&barberid[i], NULL, barbers, (void*)&i);
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         sleep(1);
      }

      /*Customer thread initialization*/
      for(i = 0; i <= customers_total; i++){ //Creation of Customer Threads 
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''  
         pthread_create(&customerid[i],NULL,customers,(void*)&i);
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         wait(); //Create customers in random interval
      }
      for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) //Waiting till all customers are dealt with

       pthread_join(customerid[i],NULL);
       printf("!!Barber Shop Closes!!\n");
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  //Exit abandoning infinite loop of barber thread
    }

    void *customers(void *param){ /*Customer Process*/

      int mySeat, B;
      static int count = 0; //Counter of No. of customers
      int numberOfFreeSeats = num_chairs; //Counter for Vacant seats in waiting room
      int seatPocket[num_chairs]; //To exchange pid between customer and barber
      int sitHereNext = 0; //Index for next legitimate seat
      serveMeNext = 0;
      sem_wait(&mutex); //Lock mutex to protect seat changes
      count++; //Arrival of customer

      printf("Customer-%d entered shop. ",count);

      if(numberOfFreeSeats > 0){
          --numberOfFreeSeats; //Sit on chairs on waiting room

        printf("Customer-%d Sits In Waiting Room.\n",count);

        sitHereNext = (++sitHereNext) % num_chairs; //Choose a vacant chair to sit

        mySeat = sitHereNext;
        seatPocket[mySeat] = count;

        sem_post(&mutex); //Release the seat change mutex
        sem_post(barbers); //Wake up one barber
        sem_wait(customers); //Join queue of sleeping customers
        sem_wait(&mutex); //Lock mutex to protect seat changes

        B = seatPocket[mySeat]; //Barber replaces customer PID with his own PID

        numberOfFreeSeats++; //Stand Up and Go to Barber Room

        sem_post(&mutex); //Release the seat change mutex
        /*Customer is having hair cut by barber 'B'*/
      }else{
        sem_post(&mutex); //Release the mutex and customer leaves without haircut  
        printf("Customer-%d Finds No Seat & Leaves.\n",count);
      }
      pthread_exit(0);
    }

    void *barbers(void *param){ /*Barber Process*/

      int index = *(int *)(param);
      int myNext, C;
      int worktime;
      int seatPocket[num_chairs]; //To exchange pid between customer and barber  

      printf("Barber-%d joins shop. ",index);

      while(1){ /*Infinite loop*/
        printf("Barber-%d Gone To Sleep.\n",index);

        sem_wait(barbers); //Join queue of sleeping barbers
        sem_wait(&mutex); //Lock mutex to protect seat changes

        serveMeNext = (++serveMeNext) % MAX; //Select next customermyNext = serveMeNext;

        C = seatPocket[myNext]; //Get selected customer's PID
        seatPocket[myNext] = pthread_self(); //Leave own PID for customer

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(customers); //Call selected customer

       /*Barber is cutting hair of customer 'C'*/
        printf("Barber-%d Wakes Up & Is Cutting Hair Of Customer-%d.\n",index,C);
        worktime = (rand() % 3) + 1;
        printf("Barber-%d Finished.\n",index);
        sleep(worktime);
      }
    }

    void wait(){ /*Generates random number between 50000 to 250000*/
      int x = rand() % (250000 - 50000 + 1) + 50000;
      srand(time(NULL));
      usleep(x); //usleep halts execution in specified miliseconds
    }
```

I marked with """ the places where I think I am wrong because of the research that I have been doing.

Comment: `customer` vs `customers`. `barber` vs `barbers`.

Comment: `sem_t mutex;`  Now **that's** confusing given that mutexes are an actual object type...

Comment: `wait(2)` happens to be the name of a system call.  Probably you have some undefined behaviour related to this fact.  I am not going to vote this question to be closed, but you need to try not to use standard library function names for your C projects, mostly if they are related to threads.  You need to post a complete, minimial and verifiable program, not snippets of code.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question, or repost.

Comment: Also, `exit(2)` is another system call that ends your complete program, not only the thread you are running.... so use `pthread_exit()` and/or `pthread_join()` to synchronize thread termination.  Don't use `exit(2)` in a thread to terminate it.

Answer (score 2):

From the warning, it is evident that you were passing a pointer to a function instead of the `sem_t` type that it expects.

You seem to have had a typo with `customer` and `barber`.

The `sem_init` must be

```
sem_init(&customer,0,0);      
sem_init(&barber,0,0);
```

And your `sem_post` must be

```
sem_post(&customer);
sem_post(&barber);
```

Also, don't forget to compile this with `-lpthread` or `-pthread`